How to compile ddmlib from source?
I downloaded the source of platform/tools/base and other repos required for the 'ddmlib', but it seems like something has been hidden form us to compile the lib from the source, i need a recipe to build it alone, someone can help me?
I'm using windows, so i need to use gradle tools to do that.
I just want to know how it works to build 'ddmlib' from source, not just obtain the ddmlib.jar from some maven repo.

You might want to check out the Gradle Manual

ddmlib sources exist in quite a few versions. Please specify exact the version you are trying use, best with link to the sources. If you try to build it what error you get? Note that Windows is often not a suitable build environment for parts of AOSP.
